# Build GoogleMaps link dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML page that uses XSLT:
This is a dynamic list that built with XSLT foreach loop.

```
<div data-role="content" id="contacts" data-c8o-listen=".GetContacts">

  <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-c8o-each="records">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
      <h3>{FirstName}&nbsp;{LastName}</h3>

        <label><b>Company:&nbsp;</b></label><span>{Company}</span><br/>
        <label><b>Phone:&nbsp;</b></label><span>{Phone}</span><br/>
        <label><b>Street:&nbsp;</b></label><span>{Street}</span><br/>
        <label><b>City:&nbsp;</b></label><span>{City}</span><br/>
        <label><b>Country:&nbsp;</b></label><span>{Country}</span>
        <button class="gm">Google map</button>
        <!-- >button data-c8o-call=".ReadContact" >
          Get Details<span style="visibility:hidden"
                        data-c8o-variable="ID">{Id:first}</span>
        </button-->
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need somehow to add a button or a link to Google maps

```
var loc = Country + "," + State + ","  + Street;
var addr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + loc +
    "&zoom=14&size=288x300&sensor=false";
```

How can I do that with jQuery? Because the list is dynamic I cannot assign ids.

Comment: Is there more than one `<div data-role="collapsible">`? Are you wanting to add a Google Maps link in all of them?

Comment: The are more, the size is dynamic. I want to add the link according to  the data in spans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [`$('selector').each(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the collapsible divs.

Your function `fn(index, element)` will then use the `element` argument (or `this`) to compute Country etc. for the current div.

Finally, you can use something like the following to add the link:

```
$(this).append('<a href="' + addr + '">Google maps</a>');
```

I'm making some guesses as to the conditions and requirements, so if the above doesn't meet your need, let me know in what ways I've guessed wrong.

### Update

An example, in response to comment. I resisted giving an example at first, since I have to guess at the specifics. But with that in mind...

```
$('div[data-role="collapsible"]').each(function(index, element) {
   // ... your code to extract Country etc. from this or element arg. ...

   var loc = Country + "," + State + ","  + Street;
   var addr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" +
      loc + "&zoom=14&size=288x300&sensor=false";
   $(this).append('<a href="' + addr + '">Google maps</a>');
});
```

Comment: One more question, in .each(function(index, element), which element the element param represents?

Comment: @NickF: In each iteration of `each()`, `element` represents the `div` currently being processed. The function is called once for each `div[data-role="collapsible"]`.